# Have == operator to ignore selected class members during object comparison

Tags: php

PHP provides a very nice way for object comparison.

```
class People {
    public $name;
}

$p0 = new People();
$p1 = new People();

$p0->name = 'ali';
$p1->name = 'ali';

// equal
if ($p0 == $p1) {
    echo 'equal' . "\n";
} else {
    echo 'diff' . "\n";
}
```

However, sometimes, I would like to have some class members to be ignored, during comparison.

```
class People {
    public $id;
    public $name;
}

$p0 = new People();
$p1 = new People();

$p0->id = 0;    // Can we ignore this id during == comparison?
$p1->id = 1;    // Can we ignore this id during == comparison?
$p0->name = 'ali';
$p1->name = 'ali';

// diff. As $p0->id != $p1->id. How can we ignore id during == comparison?
if ($p0 == $p1) {
    echo 'equal' . "\n";
} else {
    echo 'diff' . "\n";
}
```

If there any way for me to ask `==` operator to ignore selected class members?

Comment: Well then there is no need to use "==" isn't it? "==" Operator is made to check if the two objects and attributes are the same. In this case you will need to create your own method for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot overload operators in PHP. There is a [PECL extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/operator) allowing it, but it's easier (and more portable) to give your objects an `equals()` method and then compare through this, e.g.

```
class People
…
    public function equals(People $people)
    {
        return $this->name === $people->name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can compare with the `name` objects directly

```
if ($p0->name == $p1->name) {
    echo 'equal' . "\n";
} else {
    echo 'diff' . "\n";
}
```

Comment: What if I have many class members? Then the code will not look elegant.

Comment: For tat only I told to check with the class objects.You may have many objects but can check with choosen object